# how can i deduct a quantity in my database from another table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
MysqlConn.Open()
            command.Connection = MysqlConn
            command.CommandText = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE product SET `stocks` = @stocks - quantity  from 'anothertable' WHERE `itemname` = @item"
            With command.Parameters

            End With
```

I don't know how will I do that. any help ? how to get and  parameterized the rows on the database ?

Comment: `I don't know how will I do that`  This is not a tutorial site.  You need to do your own research.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `update-join` syntax like below where `some_column` is a common column (or) a relationship column (related with `FOREIGN KEY`)

```
UPDATE product p
JOIN anothertable a
ON p.some_column = a.some_column
SET `stocks` = @stocks - a.quantity  
WHERE p.`itemname` = @item;
```

Comment: how will I parameterized it ?

Comment: @TroyRicamata, that you can do some research and find out I hope